# Calculating median of 3 columns in a BigQuery table

Tags: google-bigquery, median

I am trying to build a query to calculate median of 3 column values. My table looks like below,

| Item | Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 12 | 4 |
| B | 5 | 14 | 20 |
| C | 15 | 5 | 4 |

I want to be able to output,

| Item | Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Median |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 12 | 4 | 10 |
| B | 5 | 14 | 20 | 14 |
| C | 15 | 5 | 4 | 5 |

I have tried percentile_cont() but that seems to be only for values in a single column. How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select *, 
  ( select distinct percentile_disc(col, 0.5) over() 
    from unnest([Column1, Column2, Column3]) as col
  ) AS Median
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! This worked!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
select Col1, Col2, Col3, 
       PERCENTILE_CONT([Col1, Col2, Col3], 0.5) OVER() AS Median
from   tableName
```

Comment: Yes, but that errors out as 

_No matching signature for analytic function PERCENTILE_CONT for argument types: ARRAY<FLOAT64>, FLOAT64. Supported signatures: PERCENTILE_CONT(FLOAT64, FLOAT64); PERCENTILE_CONT(NUMERIC, NUMERIC); PERCENTILE_CONT(BIGNUMERIC, BIGNUMERIC) at [5:3]_